# Laravel Eloquent Advanced HAVING

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a rather strange need from Eloquent. I need to represent the following query using the Eloquent way of doing things. The values come directly from user input so I don't know how best to proceed.

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(Table1.table2ID) AS table2ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Table1.table3ID) AS table3ID
FROM
    Table1
HAVING table2ID LIKE '%1%' AND (table3ID LIKE '%123%' OR '%456%')
    AND table2ID LIKE '%2%' AND (table3ID LIKE '%789%' OR '%012%')
```

NOTE: This is an extremely reduced version of query to reduce confusion, but this is the part I am having the issue with.

`$query->having(...)` doesn't support the closure method that `$query->where` does.

Comment: Did you consider [`havingRaw`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)?

Comment: I think that `havingRaw()` is the direction I will have to take. I wasn't sure if I was missing something entirely. I was really hoping that `having()` worked in the same way as `where()` and I was being an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

If your query is too complicated for eloquent, think that the point of eloquent is doing more readable and easy the code. There is no need to overcomplicate yourself, create a scope where you can add a raw query to your Model, like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MiModel extends Model
{

    public function scopeHasWhatIneed($query)
    {
        return $query->select(DB::raw("your complex query here"));
    }
}
```

Now you can play with your model, with understable code:

```
$mi_model->hasWhatIneed()->where(.....)->orderby...
```

Ah, notice that with raw queries you need to protect yourself from sql injection.

Comment: This is something that I did consider, so I will take an approach similar to this. I try to use Raw queries as little as possible, not just for readability but also prevention of SQL injection.

This often does make me think more complicated. I'll simplify things to get what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Due to the complexity of the actual query I'm using, I can't use this exact approach. I will however give you an upvote for the helpfulness. :)